# Price of 1 gas in dollars?

Tags: ether, gas

As of June 11, 2018, the price of 1 ether is about $520 (from https://www.coindesk.com/ethereum-price/). From https://ethgasstation.info/, the average price of 1 gas is 2 Gwei (1 Gwei=10^9 wei) which implies that the average price is 2 times the square root of $520 (about $46). It seems to be very high (an addition operation costs 1 gas). **Is there a mistake in the calculations?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 Ether` = `10^9 Gwei`

i.e. `Price of 1 Gwei` = `Price of 1 Ether` / `10^9`

Given `Price of 1 Ether` = `520` dollars

`Price of 1 Gwei` = `5.2 * 10^-7` dollars or `0.000052` cents.

Thus if `1 gas` = `2 Gwei`, then `1 gas` = `0.000104` cents.

Not sure why your calculation involved a square root.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a mistake in your calculations. I’m guessing you’re not familiar with the notation used. 1 gwei is a billion (1 000 000 000, also written as 10^9, which is 1 followed by 9 zeroes) wei and there are 10^18 (1 followed by 18 zeroes, or 1 000 000 000 000 000 000) wei in one ether. So if one gas is 2 gwei and 1 ether is $520, then one gas is 2 * 10^9 / 10^18 ether=2 * 1 000 000 000 / 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 ether = 0.000 000 002 ether = 2 * 10^(-9) ether. And that is about $0.000 001. Or about one ten-thousandths of a cent.

Comment: There is a problem here with the definition of 1Gwei. It is `1e9`not `1e6`.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of 1 unit of gas depends on whatever the gas price is set to.

```
gasCost = gasPrice * gasAmount
```

At 2 gwei, and 1 gas, the calculation will look like this:

```
gasCost = 2*10^9 * 1
gasCost = 2*10^9 wei
gasCost (USD) = ~ 0$
```